# Customizing database fields for trackable module in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In my Rails application, I would like to add `Trackable` module to `Devise`.

As a default, it suggests to add the following fields to the users database:

```
  t.integer  :sign_in_count, :default => 0, :null => false
  t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
  t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
  t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
  t.string   :last_sign_in_ip
```

I don't care about user ip and current_sign_in_at. Can I safely comment out the fields I don't need as follows

```
  t.integer  :sign_in_count, :default => 0, :null => false
  #t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
  t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
  #t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
  #t.string   :last_sign_in_ip
```

Will `Trackable` still work?

Comment: Don't be afraid, go ahead and try it, if it doesn't work, comeback.

Comment: Since he never came back , I can assume that it works.